# How do I update diamond with conda?

Tags: conda

I am trying to run the program checkm2 (https://github.com/chklovski/CheckM2). I installed with mamba:
`mamba create -n checkm2 -c bioconda -c conda-forge checkm2`
However, I am getting an error that can be resolved by updating diamond from 2.0.4 to 2.1.6 as per this post: https://github.com/chklovski/CheckM2/issues/58. However, when I try `conda update diamond` the update does not work:

```
    (checkm2) rmaher2@UO-2008381 ~ % conda update diamond                     
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done


==> WARNING: A newer version of conda exists. <==
  current version: 23.3.1
  latest version: 23.5.0

Please update conda by running

    $ conda update -n base -c conda-forge conda

Or to minimize the number of packages updated during conda update use

     conda install conda=23.5.0



## Package Plan ##

  environment location: /Users/rmaher2/miniconda3/envs/checkm2

  added / updated specs:
    - diamond


The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

  colorama           conda-forge/noarch::colorama-0.4.4-pyh9f0ad1d_0 

The following packages will be UPDATED:

  rsa                     bioconda/osx-64::rsa-3.1.4-py36_0 --> conda-forge/noarch::rsa-4.9-pyhd8ed1ab_0 
  tqdm                   bioconda/osx-64::tqdm-4.7.2-py36_0 --> conda-forge/noarch::tqdm-4.65.0-pyhd8ed1ab_0 


Proceed ([y]/n)? y


Downloading and Extracting Packages

Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done
(checkm2) rmaher2@UO-2008381 ~ % diamond --version
diamond version 2.0.4
```

Any suggestions on how to update diamond?

Comment: Try `mamba install -c bioconda -c conda-forge diamond==2.1.6`

Comment: I get the error:

`Pinned packages:`
`- python 3.6.*`


`Could not solve for environment specs`
`Encountered problems while solving:`
  `- package checkm2-1.0.1-pyh7cba7a3_0 requires diamond 2.0.4.*, but none of the providers can be installed`

`The environment can't be solved, aborting the operation`